# Forced to install GDAL 1.11 framework by package for QGIS, and failing

Tags: gdal, qgis

To install QGIS on my MacBook Pro I need to install the gdal framework; however, the 1.11 framework package needed for QGIS is an empty file at [kyngchaos](http://www.kyngchaos.com/software/frameworks#gdal_complete). I tried installing GDAL 1.10 complete, but QGIS is requiring 1.11. I have Mavericks. I've installed each individual package: UnixImageIO, PROJ, GEOS, SQLite2, numpy, rgdal, and on... Now when I run the GDAL 1.11 framework install, everything seems to run until the last page, where an "Install Fail" page shows up. When I try to view the error, I'm taken out of the installer.

After some googling, I tried installing using homebrew. (brew install gdal)... I got a little further, but it tells me to "brew link libpng libtiff" -- and when I run that command, I get:

> Linking /usr/local/Cellar/libpng/1.5.14... Warning: Could not link libpng. Unlinking...
>
> Error: Could not symlink file: /usr/local/Cellar/libpng/1.5.14/share/man/man3/libpngpf.3
> /usr/local/share/man/man3 is not writable. You should change its permissions.

After some more searching, it seems I could change permissions from usr/local to me, but I'm not sure how to (exactly) and don't want to mess anything up. Any help would be greatly appreciated, and my apologies if I'm missing something painfully obvious! I'm a novice at the programming end of things, so am just kind of pushing through everything like a bull in a china shop.

---

UPDATE:
Okay, I found the answer, even though it didn't seem to be working initially--

I ran the following commands from the GDAL help documentation:

> export PATH=/Library/Frameworks/GDAL.framework/Programs:$PATH
>
> sudo ln -sfh [ver] /Library/Frameworks/GDAL.framework/Versions/Current

in Terminal, and the framework was updated. If I run the GDAL 1.11 installer it still shows up as a failed installation, BUT QGIS recognizes 1.11 as the installed, so that's great.

(I just needed to install matplotlib in addition, and QGIS was installed successfully.)

It seems that the GDAL Complete framework was just updated 3 days ago, so it should be a temporary error until they realize the package is empty.

Comment: good followthrough and updating, OP